# Invalid null pointer

Tags: c++

Выделяю память для производных классов Radio,TV или PC  под указатель ptr на базовый класс BC. Должно работать, но выдает ошибку `debug assertion failed invalid null pointer:`

не подскажете, что сделать?

```
int Container::registration()
{
    int buf;
    BC*ptr;
    do
    {
    cout<<"Введите,какое информационное агенство хотите выбрать:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Печатное издание"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Радиостанция"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Телекомпания"<<endl;
    buf=checkinput();
    }while((buf!=1)&&(buf!=2)&&(buf!=3));
    string name;
    cout<<"Введите имя информационного агенства"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    map<const string,BC*>::iterator cur;
    for(cur=CT.begin();cur!=CT.end();cur++)
    {
        if(name==(*cur).first)
            throw "Данное имя идентификатора присутствует";
    }
    if (buf==1)
    {
        ptr=new PC;
        PC*subptr=dynamic_cast<PC*>(ptr);
        cin>>ptr;
        subptr->fill(ptr);
        CT.insert(pair<const string,BC*>(name,ptr));
        return 1;
    }
    if (buf==2)
    {
        ptr=new Radio;
        Radio*subptr=dynamic_cast<Radio*>(ptr);
        cin>>ptr;
        subptr->fill(ptr);
        CT.insert(pair<const string,BC*>(name,ptr));
        return 1;
    }
    if (buf==3)
    {
        ptr=new TV;
        TV*subptr=dynamic_cast<TV*>(ptr);
        cin>>ptr;
        subptr->fill(ptr);
        CT.insert(pair<const string,BC*>(name,ptr));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dimamephi, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А отладчиком пробегались? на какой строчке исключение получаете?

Comment: > `BC*ptr;`  
> `cin>>ptr`

Вы вводите значение указателя с консоли? o_O

Comment: Нет это перегруженный оператор

Comment: Спасибо за быстрое реагирование но я уже нашел ошибку,она была в пустом конструкторе)